# Linear Approximation and Volume of Cylinder

Tags: linear-approximation

I was given the question:

The volume V of a cylinder is computed using the values 6m for the diameter and 9.8m for the height. Use the linear approximation to estimate the maximum error in V if each of these values has a possible error of at most 7%.

I am unsure how to begin this problem. All I can assume is to use the volume formula. Any ideas?

Comment: Start by understanding the problem statement. What, for instance, does it mean by “the linear approximation?”

Comment: I am aware of the formula. In simple terms I know with a function it is used to approximate points at (a,b) with points close to such.

Comment: This looks like you need a total differential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ V= \pi r^2 h $$

$$ dV= \frac {dV}{dr} dr + \frac {dV}{dh} dh$$
$$ = (2\pi rh) dr + (\pi r^2)dh$$

$$ \frac {dV}{V} = 2(dr/r)+ (dh/h) = 2(.07)+ (.07) = 0.21 $$

Thus the relative error in $V$ is $21$ percent.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Volume of a cylinder $V=\dfrac{\pi}{4}d^2\cdot h$

Possible error in volume $$=\frac{\pi}{4}[(1\pm0.007)d]^2[(1\pm0.007)h]$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{4}[(1\pm0.007)^3]d^2\cdot h$$
$$=v(1\pm0.07)^3$$
Now the percentage error in v $=1.225042$v $=>+22.5043$%

Comment: Hello, that means V lies between v*1.225043 and v*0.804357. Now how to compute percentage of error?

Comment: The error in v is either of the both.

Comment: If I calculated v correctly, I got 277.09. So multiplying it by v(1±0.07)^3 will give me the percentage error of V?

Comment: The possible percentage error is in v is either $+22.5043$% or $-19.5643$%

Comment: What would be used as the experimental and actual value? The computer system is saying it is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of problems, logarithmic dfifferentiation is quite useful$$V=\dfrac{\pi}{4}d^2\, h\implies \log(V)=\log\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)+2\log(d)+\log(h)$$ Take the partial derivatives
$$\frac 1 V\frac{\partial V}{\partial d}=\frac 2 d\qquad \text{and}\qquad \frac 1 V\frac{\partial V}{\partial h}=\frac 1 h$$ Going from $\partial$ to $\Delta$ and adding the contributions, we then have
$$\frac{\Delta V} V=2\frac{\Delta d } d+\frac{\Delta h } h$$ Since the relative errors are the same, then $\frac{\Delta V} V$ is three times the relative error on each dimension.